# How do I find the complement of 0x87654321 using bitwise C operations?

Tags: c, hex, bitmask

I am learning about masking techniques in C. 
Here is a practice problem I am working on: 
Need to find the complement of  0x87654321 while leaving the least significant byte intact which should look like this  0x789ABC21

The only mask I'm familiar with right now is using x & 0xFF to strip all but the last byte. I don't know which bitwise operator to use to get the complement of a hex number. How do I approach that?

My book doesn't explain what a one complement of a hex number is but I googled that and found out the shortcut method to determine a one complement is to take 15 - hexDigit = complement Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `0x87654321U ^ 0xFFFFFF00U`

Comment: Why does this produce the complement though?

Comment: Because XOR is the Boolean "not equal" function. When we XOR some value X against a Boolean 1/True (X XOR True) we are saying "X not equal to True", which is the same as "X not True" which is just "not X", which is complement.  The C ^ operator applies the Boolean XOR function in parallel across all the corresponding bits of the operands.  So we can use a *mask* like 0xFFFFFF00 to  pick which bits we want to complement.  XOR-ing with 0 does nothing; X XOR 0 is X.  XOR-ing with 1 flips 1 to 0 and 0 to 1..

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise complement operator in C is the tilde `~`. This flips every bit in a bit pattern.

The bitwise XOR operator (`^`) can also be used to do a bitwise complement. The bitwise XOR truth table is below:

```
^| 0 1
------
0| 0 1
1| 1 0
```

Notice in particular that 1^0 = 1 and that 1^1 = 0. Thus, bitwise XOR with a one will also have the effect of flipping bits.

Thus, bitwise XOR with `0xFFFFFF00` will flip all but the last eight bits of a number.